# Annotation for Dropdown sending Values to extract values

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-gateway

I am working with a SAP NW 7.4 and I am using OData with Annotations (no CDS, SEGW & Code) for SAPUI5 Apps. These apps are built with Smartform and Smartfields.

My question is: I have to extract the info an entitySet which is used as `ValueList` in SAPUI5 but, I should receive some parameters from the screen when the call to the OData Service is called.

I tried to send the Parameter from my Entity Type to the related Entity by creating a new `ParemeterIn` as in the following picture:

[image: Definition of Parameter]

With the following:

[image: Mapping of Value]

But only works when it is displayed as "SearchHelp".

I searched here and on SAP but I cannot find anything similar that helps me out. Suggestions???